# Joda Date and SWT DateTime conflict

Tags: eclipse, datetime, swt

I've run into a problem I haven't seen before and a search pulled up nothing. 
I have imported SWT DateTime and Joda DateTime in my program, and it doesn't seem like they can co-exist. is there a way to allow both classes in eclipse?It keeps wanting to use swt DateTime widget exclusively, and I'm not sure how to deal with two classes of the same name in different imports. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just skip both imports and reference the classes using the full package name:

```
public class Main {
    private org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime;
    private swt.DateTime swtDateTime;
}
```

Comment: Or you can import the one you use more often and still refer to the other with the full name.